# Laravel 5.3 Complex DB Update Query with Select, Joins and CONCAT notworking

Tags: laravel, sqlite, sql-update, phpunit, laravel-5.3

I wrote an sql update query. It is working on Mysql Workbench. I put the sql update query in laravels db update. When I am testing it with phpunit I am getting an error. The phpunit uses sqlite.

The following error appears when I run the unit test:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "as": syntax error (SQL: UPDATE table1 as mainp LEFT JOIN ....)
```

When I am removing "as mainp" the following error appears:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "LEFT": syntax error (SQL: UPDATE table1 as mainp LEFT JOIN ....)
```

Here is the whole update query

```
\DB::connection($this->dbConnection)->update(\DB::raw("
    UPDATE table1 as mainp left join
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
        (
            select p.fullname, cc.surname as name_one, cc.forename as name_two
            from table1 as p
                LEFT JOIN table2 as cc
                on p.fullname LIKE CONCAT(cc.surname,'%')
                LEFT JOIN table2 as cc2
                on p.fullname LIKE CONCAT('%',cc.forename)
        ) AS pcccc
        WHERE fullname = CONCAT(name_one, name_two)
    ) AS main
    ON mainp.fullname = main.fullname
    SET mainp.name_one = main.name_one,
    mainp.name_two = main.name_two")
);
```

All the tables are created. When I am using db::select I am getting some result.

```
return \DB::connection($this->dbConnection)->select(\DB::raw("select p.fullname, cc.surname as name_one, cc.forename as name_two
        from table1 as p
            LEFT JOIN table2 as cc
            on p.fullname LIKE CONCAT(cc.surname,'%')
            LEFT JOIN table2 as cc2
            on p.fullname LIKE CONCAT('%',cc.forename)"));
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your sql is not valid, it contains both `as` and `left join` which shouldn't be there: `UPDATE table(...columns) TableAlias SET (...values)`

Comment: I am still getting an error: `Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "(": syntax error`

Comment: make sure that your sql is valid i don't think it's a phpunit error

Comment: The sql is valid. I have tested it on a sql client. After successful testing I copied the sql query into laravel. I also tested it with `\DB::connection($this->dbConnection)->statement(\DB::raw("UPDATE 
            table1 (name_one, name_two) 
            SET ('test1', 'test2')"));` and I am getting the same error. When I am using as select query on table tabl1 it is working.

Comment: Compact your query into a single line, and then try, I think `Laravel` has issues when executing multiline string, so try compacting that big query into 1 line

Comment: I compacted it into one line. Still the same error. All the errors issues after `UPDATE table1 ...`. table1 exists but the update query cannot handle it. I can access to tabl1 with select query.

Comment: I tested it again with mysql and it's working with compacting it into one line. The problem still exists with sqlite. I can live with it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: MySQL and SQLite speak different SQL dialects.